# How to fix msimg32.dll registration

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have read that many execution problems may be related to `msimg32.dll` and could be fixed registering the dll again with

```
regsvr32 msimg32.dll
```

If I try this on my pc get the error:

> The module "msimg32.dll" was loaded but the entry-point
>   dllRegisterServer was not found Make sure that "msimg32.dll" is a
>   valid dll or ocx file and then try again

What is this file exactly? How could I fix it in Windows 8.1 x64?

Note that the file is already present in *system32* folder

Comment: What problem are you having that makes you want to reregister the dll?

Comment: Seems like the windows missing some dll file. So, you run this command "SFC /Scannow" to copy the missing dll files in windows.

Comment: I have already launched sfc /scannow and has not found any issue.

Answer (score 0):

regsvr32 can be only used if the DLL is a [ActiveX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) component and provides a function  `dllRegisterServer` so that it can be globally registered.

Your DLL is a normal Windows DLL and NO ActiveX DLL so you can't register it. You should as a new question and explain which msimg32.dll related issue you have.